# Pattern rules work but suffix rules don't

Tags: makefile, posix, gnu-make

Pattern rules work:

```
$ ls
Makefile   hello.txt  world.txt
$ cat Makefile
all: hello.out world.out

%.out: %.txt
        cp $< $@

$ make
cp hello.txt hello.out
cp world.txt world.out
```

However, when I try to replace them with what I think is the exact equivalent suffix rules, they don't work:

```
$ ls
Makefile   hello.txt  world.txt
$ cat Makefile
.POSIX:
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES:.txt.out

all: hello.out world.out

.txt.out:
        cp $< $@

$ make
make: *** No rule to make target 'hello.out', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
```

I don't understand why.

Comment: Side note: unless you need to support ancient versions of Make, `SUFFIXES` is obsolete, you can just use pattern rules.

Comment: @user657267: No. You should always use the smallest subset that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
.SUFFIXES: .txt.out
```

It declares a single suffix, `.txt.out`, not two of them.  You can change it to this:

```
.SUFFIXES: .txt .out
```